# How to get url in Layout view using ASP.net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I need to migrate an `MVC` project into `.net Core`, I know that `System.Web` was removed from `ASP.net Core`, I need to get the current `url` and depending of the value of it then display the same `layout` but with some changes.

This is the code I have in MVC and I need to translate into ASP.net Core:

```
 public class LIGCalculators
    {

        public static bool LargePano(Uri url)
        {

            var path = url.AbsolutePath.ToLower();
            if (path == "/")
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (path.Contains("Home"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

`Layout` view(MVC), `Request.Url` doesn't work in `Core`:

```
  @if (LIGCalculators.LargePano(Request.Url))
    {
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="pano-bg"></div>
        <div class="bgs">
            <div class="orangeL"></div>
            <div class="blue2L"></div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="blue-big"></div>
        <div class="small-pano-bg"></div>
        <div class="bgs">
            <div class="orange"></div>
            <div class="blue2"></div>
        </div>
    }
```

This is not showing errors in ASP.net Core, but how do I call this method from the layout? How to send the url as parameter?:

```
 public static bool LargePano(Uri url)
        {
           // return true;
            var path = url.AbsolutePath.ToLower();
            if (path == "/")
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (path.Contains("Home"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I did it using this code:

```
 @{ 
           Uri url = new Uri(String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}", Context.Request.Scheme, Context.Request.Host, Context.Request.Path, Context.Request.QueryString));           
        }
```